# How to add a children data through user exit class in Maximo inbound integration?

Tags: integration, maximo

I have an object structure with 3 objects. location > lochierarchy > customtable.
On the original source xml -erdata, I get only details for location object. I have derived the information for lochierarchy and the customtable.

If I have at least one column value for lochierarchy and customtable, I am able to use the following code and fill up the derived values.
xml

```
<LOCATIONS>
 <location>1000</location>
 <siteid>xyg</siteid>
 <LOCHIERARCHY>
  <SYSTEMID>abdc</SYSTEMID>
  <PARENT></PARENT>
   <CUSTOMTABLE>
    <DEPT>MECHANICAL</DEPT>
    <OWNER></OWNER>
   </CUSTOMTABLE>
  </LOCHIERARCHY>
```

```
 List locHierarchyList =irData.getChildrenData("LOCHIERARCHY");
           int locHrSize=locHierarchyList.size();
           for (int i=0;i<locHrSize;i++)
            {
                irData.setAsCurrent(locHierarchyList,i);
                irData.setCurrentData("PARENT","xyyyyg");

          List customTablerList =irData.getChildrenData("CUSTOMTABLE");
           int custSize=customTablerList .size();
           for (int i=0;i<custSize;i++)
            {
              //set values
            }
```

But I am getting the source xml with only the location data below and I'm trying to build the children data. I am missing something here.

Incoming XML

```
    <LOCATIONS>
     <location>1000</location>
     <siteid>xyg</siteid>
</LOCATIONS>
```

My Code

```
irData.createChildrenData("LOCHIERARCHY");
   irData.setAsCurrent();

    irData.setCurrentData("SYSTEMID", SYSTEM);
    irData.setCurrentData("PARENT", parentLoc);


    irData.createChildrenData("CUSTOMTABLE");
    irData.setAsCurrent();
```

but this is not working. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, just had to use another method of createChildrenData.

```
  irData.createChildrenData("LOCHIERARCHY",true);
```

This one did the trick. It creates the child set and make it as current.